# как зациклить код python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-2.7

Есть такой вот код

```
import pyautogui 
import webbrowser
import time
 
#ссылка
 
s = input("Ссылка на ролик:")
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1215, 180, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1124, 363, duration = 0.2)
 
time.sleep(5)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(2)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 215, 2, duration = 1)
 
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 245, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 275, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 305, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 335, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 365, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 395, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
 
webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1013, 136, duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click(1087, 183, 2, duration = 1)
 
time.sleep(3)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(3)
```

Мне нужно чтобы после окончания последнего действия он начинался заново но без input , ну тоесть чтобы заново открывалась вкладка , курсор на заданое место и тд , но я не знаю как это сделать , пробовал через while ничего не получилось , подскажите пожалуйста как сделать

Comment: А вы браузеры только открываете и не закрываете? У вас ресурсы так не кончатся?

Answer (score 0):

Можно после `s = input('ссылка:')` на следующей строчке написать `while True:` а дальше весь код писать через Tab(4 пробела)